# iOS / Android: designing app, all-native or PhoneGap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

In the company I work for, I'm part of a team which will have to focus on mobile apps development (iOS and Android).

We are committed to realize our first commercial app, for both iOS and Android, and since the first meetings the team is discussing about which is the better development approach for it, if the native languages and development environments for the targeting platforms or HTML5 through PhoneGap.

We already know about the technical differences between the two worlds, but one aspect we are debating on is about the appearance.

Also please notice that the only networking features the app will have are related to HTTP requests.

In fact, the app we're talking about is required to have a quite customized UI, with particular button and listview appearance, for instance. To be more precise, we're not only talking about colors, but also circular buttons.

This kind of canvas lets some of us to think that HTML5/PhoneGap could be a faster and more flexible solution, due to the obvious design power you have on your hands, paired with development speed and targeting 2 apps with 1 code base.

Would someone suggest which approach (between all-native and HTML5/PhoneGap) could be preferable when a customized appearance is required?

Comment: Why not throw Titanium into the mix, and get the best of both worlds..?

Comment: @BillyMoon: because - after our evaluation - we already chose PhoneGap over Titanium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I prefer to write applications in native and I can tell you why. First of all it's not really hard to write an application which is connecting to web server and do some things. I'm not really familiar with PhoneGap or all kinds of software which lets you develop mobile applications with HTML5, CSS and Javascript, but I don't think that this type of development will let you use all libraries and everything you can do with Android or Iphone. I think the best way to develop an application for Android or Iphone is to use their native tools/languages because there is a reason why Google/Apple decide to use this type of development (Java/Objective C). But of course when you are working in a company you have to consider the time spend on an application and the money which will cost to build it.

Comment: And just another thing : if your company will continue building mobile applications at some point you will have problems if you are using HTML5 and JS to build your applications (as I said I'm not really familiar with the possibilities which these kind of software lets you code for Android/Iphone, it's just my opinion). In some point you will have to start using native development.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy answer to this, depending on who you talk to you are going to get a different answer. I am in similar position as you, where I have been hired to create a customizable app, we are still in the process of deciding whether to go HTML5 or Native. I have been making some mock Apps to test in both HTML5 and native, and I find it hard to declare a true winner.

I would say its probably easier to make the app more customizable with HTML5, but I personally find it more enjoyable to design and code the app natively but that's just my opinion. I would say create a quick mock app in both HTML5 and in Native and then decide which one you prefer. That's what I have been doing,

Answer (score 1):

I'm agree with Android-Droid....

It would be nice based on your description to create the app in native. In iOS, there is much library that can used for developing so your app will be on max features. But, if you consider the time and money spend, hmmm......

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the choice between Native and Phonegap should be a matter of requirements. If you want to kill more birds with one stone, then go with Phonegap especially with its recent acquisition by adobe, it has become even more reliable with companies like Linked in building their mobile apps in HTML5. 
also most native libraries features are supported in all major platforms the only one with shady support i can think of is NFC which only a very few native developers use in any case.So there is no better approach all approaches are good but requirements should be the deciding factor.

Answer (score 0):

I Had been through these...

It will always be a better choice to create a native app (Rich UI, Better Perfromance )
, than using phonegap.